# generate link based on field values in access

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, vba

We have an archive of reports that are automatically saved and named according to a test number (A) and request number (B), resulting in a directory similar to  C:\archivefolder\B_A.  I am creating a table in access that includes fields for A and B and I would like to add a third field that contains a hyperlink to the related report.  My plan is to automatically generate the link by providing the first portion of the directory (C:\arvhivefolder) and then concatenate the remaining portion based on what is entered into the other two fields (A and B).

What I've done so far creates the correct directory and copies it into the hyperlink field, but the link won't work.  If I copy and paste the the link into another field, "##" is added to the end of the line (C:\archivefolder\B_A##).  When I delete the "##", the link works.

Can anyone help me with this?  As far as I can tell, I'm  renaming the link, but not changing the address/ directory.

Here is what I've done so far:

To create the full directory, I created a field, named ResultsLink, with a calculated data type where the expression is:

`"C:\archivefolder\" & [B] & "_" & [A] & ".pdf"`

I don't believe there is a way to generate a link from this calculated field, so I created another field with a hyperlink data type and named it ResultsPDF.  Then I created a macro to copy the value from the ResultsLink field into the ResultsPDF field (it's a click-button for now, will change later):

```
Me.ResultsPDF.Value = ResultsLink.Value
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
```

When I click the button, the hyperlink field is updated with what appears to be an active link, but goes nowhere.

Comment: Please paste the full expression. `"C:archivefolder"` is missing slashes, and it doesn't seem possible that expression produces what you say it does.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to detail; I've removed my mistake from the original post.

Comment: It is possible to programmatically construct a valid hyperlink and save into hyperlink type field. A hyperlink has 3 parts http://allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html. Or use a simple string in a function to open a file in its native app. Try FollowHyperlink or  http://allenbrowne.com/func-GoHyperlink.html or use Shell mehod.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to June7 for posting the links in the comments.  I changed my macro to include the pound signs and it works perfectly now:

`Me.ResultsPDF.Value = "#" & ResultsLink.Value & "#"
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False`